# How to tell which items a ListView is showing?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

This question relates to WinRT.

How can I know which items are currently showing on a ListView (partially or fully)?

Barring that, how do I find what the top item in the ListView is?

Looked around the ListView class and couldn't really find anything.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate.  The other question is about WPF, this one is about WinRT.

Comment: Then maybe OP should edit the post to clearly indicate that? Right now it's either "duplicate" or "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: Please remove duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

To find the top one you can do:

```
ListViewItem topItem = listView1.TopItem;
```

Not sure about seeing how far down is visible, but if it's helpful you can also do...

```
listView1.Items[0].EnsureVisible();
```

...to make a specific item in the list visible - it'll scroll for you automatically if needed.

Comment: ListView http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview doesn't have TopItem property.

Comment: Yeah - this is on Windows 8 (as the tags suggest). :(